# Pythonw crash without any log?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a pythonw application , running with a daemon to watch child process status.

So it has 2 process when system normal. Once a worker-process die, daemon process will fork a new worker-process in 10 second.

But after deploy this application to ~40 servers, I found that sometimes , these 2 process may die together and I can't trace or reproduce this situation.

Here is the code of daemon process, simple:

```
import subprocess
import time
import os
import sys

import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'boot.log'), level = logging.INFO, filemode = 'w', format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

def main():

    _process = None

    argv = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'pythonw.exe'), "worker.py"]
    if sys.argv[1:]:
        argv += sys.argv[1:]


    while 1:
        _process = None
        logging.info("create a new worker instance!")
        _process = subprocess.Popen(argv)
        _process.wait()
        time.sleep(10)
        logging.info("worker instance has terminated!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

More clues:

1. Here is the log:

   ```
   2014-02-18 15:42:10,015 - INFO: create a new bootuser instance!
   2014-02-21 15:42:22,226 - INFO: worker instance has terminated!
   2014-02-21 15:42:22,226 - INFO: create a new worker instance!
   2014-02-24 15:42:33,365 - INFO: worker instance has terminated!
   2014-02-24 15:42:33,365 - INFO: create a new worker instance!
   2014-02-27 15:42:14,336 - INFO: worker instance has terminated!
   2014-02-27 15:42:14,336 - INFO: create a new worker instance!
   2014-02-28 15:42:25,384 - INFO: worker instance has terminated!
   2014-02-28 15:42:25,384 - INFO: create a new worker instance!
   ```

   **Notice**: I have an self-updating procedure inside worker-process would terminate itself.
2. I can't determine how often this occur, seems random
3. This application running as a service by SYSTEM ( in windows 2008 R2)

Comment: why you are using this: while 1:

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun, It is explained in the question: `Once a worker-process die, daemon process will fork a new worker-process in 10 second`

Comment: Going to need some more clues. What does the logging output look like? How often does this occur? Any particular time of day or night it happens? Is this running under Administrator?

Comment: why `pythonw.exe` is in `os.getcwd()`? What is `p.returncode`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian we sealed python into our application.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian and unfortunately we didn't record `p.returncode`

Comment: @jackalope: Can you reproduce the error at all? How do you want to fix it if you can't to reproduce it? Are there any signs in the log that `Popen()` started successfully even once i.e., the gap is not 10 seconds all the time?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I just wanna know in what situation this gonna be happen. For now, I wrap these code with try..except , I'll update this  question once I get more clues.

Comment: @jackalope: `close_fds=True` won't hurt. As well as providing absolute paths for everything. Though I don't see the point of `os.path.join` with `os.getcwd()`. Also, `os.getcwd()` and a directory where the script is saved can be different directories. Pointing `sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr` to a file and defining `sys.excepthook` to log to a file also might help.